# How to get tokens to words in BERT tokenizer

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model, huggingface-tokenizers

I have a list, using higgingface bert tokenizer I can get the mapping numerical representation.

```
X = ['[CLS]', '[MASK]', 'love', 'this', '[SEP]']
tokens = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(X)
toekns: [101, 103, 2293, 2023, 102]
```

Is there any function so that I can get tokens=[101, 103, 2293, 2023, 102] to words ['[CLS]', '[MASK]', 'love', 'this', '[SEP]']?

One possible way is to mapping, but is there any defined function to do it easily ?

Comment: `tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(tokens, skip_special_tokens=False)`?